# promise all return error too many requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, request, request-promise

I'm using promise all for send multiple promises and I get this error

> 429 - {"error":{"code":"TooManyRequests","message":"Too many
>   requests"}}

I have list of data and I chunk data by group of 10 and then I send for each of them notification

```
 await Promise.all(usersList.map(usersTokens=> {

                    return sendPush(heading, content,usersTokens, platform).catch((e) => {
                        console.error(e)
                        errors.push({ e, android })
                    })
                }))
```

send push function

```
import * as rp from 'request-promise'
export const sendPush = (title="",secondTitle,tokens,platform) => {


let message = {
    notification_content : {
        name:title,
        title : secondTitle,
        body : secondTitle,

     },
       notification_target : {
       type : "devices_target",
       devices : tokens
     },
   }

 var headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "X-API-Token": 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
};

var options = {
    uri: `https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/apps/XXXXXXXXXX/${platform}/push/notifications`,
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers,
    body: message,
    json: true
}

  return rp(options)
```

}

Comment: The error message is most probably coming from the web service you are using. You should lower the rate of requests per minute. This means adding delays.

Comment: per minute it's too much for me..because it's to send notification for people

Comment: I am not saying one per minute. I am talking of a *rate*, like when you say a car should drive 120 km / hour, it does not mean it has to drive for one hour. :-)

Comment: @t.j.crowder I agree that this is a dupe, but the answer is a bit outdated / overcomplicated if running on nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

> I chunk data by group of 10

But you still request *all the chunks at the same time*. Therefore chunking makes less sense. Instead of using `Promise.all` you should use a loop and `await` each chunk before processing the next one:

```
 const result = [];

 for(const userTokens of userList) {
   try {
     result.push(await sendPush(heading, content,usersTokens, platform));
   } catch(e) {
     console.error(e)
     errors.push({ e, android })
  }
}
```

If that is still too fast for the API, you could [delay the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44476626/5260024)

Comment: why to push all promise into result array? I tried before to use in for but somtimes I get from server error of 'timeout' maybe in for loop it takes more time each promise?

Comment: @adir it does push the Promises results, you don't need that if the API does not return something meaningful. And a timeout means you should retry the operation a bit later

Comment: yes but when it shows me timeout and I'm waiting for answer from the push so the system is crash.

Comment: but I will try your way,